# bringing the integer value from the database and add 1 to that value

Tags: javascript, jsp

hi frnds i am working with jsp and javascript. i had an input field name called as billno and the billno value is 1 and after clicking save it will save to database. my problem is after clicking save the billno should increase with +1 automatically and next time it should save with 2.whenever i opens  the app it should show the next billno. so plz help me

```
 <div class="reg-form">
     <form method="post" name="sales" action="sales">
            <table class="main">
               <thead>
                  <tr>
                     <th>SALES
                     </th>
                  </tr>
               </thead>
            </table>
            <table class="in-sec-small">  
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td class="label">
                        <label for="patient-type">PATIENT TYPE
                        </label>
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <select id="patient_type" class="textfield-form-req-select" type="text" name="patient_type" required>
                           <option value="member">IP</option>
                           <option value="non-member">OP</option>
                            <option value="non-member">WIP</option>
                        </select>
                     </td>
                     <td class="label">
                        <label for="reg-type">REG TYPE
                        </label>
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <select id="reg_type" class="textfield-form-req-select" type="text" name="reg_type" required>
                           <option value="member">Member</option>
                           <option value="non-member">Non Member</option>
                        </select>
                     </td>
                     <td class="label">
                        <label for="bill-no">BILL NO
                        </label>
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <input id="bill_no"  class="textfield-form-date-req" type="text" name="bill_no"  required>
                     </td>
```

Comment: you can use ajax to get the value of the bill no from the database and then add 1 and display

Comment: i dont know ajax plz help me on how to do it

Comment: u can learn ajax from here http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/Default.Asp

Comment: there is no way using java script

Comment: this site has...http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ajax/ajax_database.htm

Comment: no one is there to solve my problem using java script...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49447/discussion-between-amit-183-and-saideep)

Answer (score 0):

Include this in your javascript:

```
   $(function() {
    var t1=0;
    $.ajax({type:'POST',url:'to_some_url.php'}).done(function(data){
        t1=data;
        t1=data+1;
        $('#bill_no').val(t1);


        });

});
```

Now to_some_url.php:

```
<?php
 ini_set( "display_errors", 0);
 gc_enable();
 //Now Initialise yor db conncetion

 $result_query=$mysqli->query("SELECT LAST(billno) FROM table_name");
 $row=$result_query->fetch_array();
 $biil_no=$row['billno'];
 echo $bill_no;
?>
```

now you can modify your code according to your requirements